# Is there a way to use the `chrome` namespace in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a WebExtension that runs in both firefox and chrome (also, I need the extension to work as a webpage when I visit the html that the build leaves). In this context, I want to use the `chrome.storage.local` storage. However, when I try to use it in the webpage in Chrome, `storage` isn't defined and I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

As a workaround, I'm considering to use `window.localStorage` if `location.protocol` is different than 'chrome-extension:' or 'moz-extension:', but I'd like to know if there is a way to make `chrome.storage` work in the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some chrome APIs (eg. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`) are available to regular pages, but `chrome.storage` is not one of them. It is only available to extensions that request the `storage` permission in their `manifest.json`. This is stated in the documentation for both [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) and [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage).